# Forming Partial Fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have:

$ \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)h(x)} $

and we want to break it down into:

$$ \frac{I(x)}{g(x)} +  \frac{J(x)}{h(x)}$$

and that

$$\deg(f) \leq \deg(g)+\deg(h),\quad \deg(I) < \deg(g), \quad\deg(J) < \deg(h).$$

What is the general way of doing this?

I don't understand the intuition behind having to express;

$\frac{ax^{2}+bx+c }{(dx+e)(f x^{2}+g) } = \frac{A}{dx+e} + \frac{Bx+C}{fx ^{2}+g }$.

Is there a general rule I'm missing?

Thanks.

Edit: Just to clarify, these are all polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

**First** what is the generalized theorem?

> **Theorem** Given three polynomials $P,Q,R$such that $\gcd(P,Q)=1$ there exists $U,V$ such that:
> $$\frac{R(x)}{P(x)Q(x)}=\frac{U(x)}{P(x)}+\frac{V(x)}{Q(x)} $$
> with $\deg(U)+\deg(R)< \deg(P), \deg(V)+\deg(R)<\deg(Q)$

*Proof* It follows easily from [Bézout's identity and extended GCD algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm)

As we observe the condition $P$ and $Q$ being relatively coprime are necessary for the validity of the theorem because we can find simple examples which does not satisfy the theorem.

**Second** how to compute $U$ and $V$?

- Algebraic method using the extended GCD algorithm, which is the general method and it always works
- Analytic method, for example, if we want to find $U$ and we know the roots of $P$ we know that $deg(U)\leq deg(P)$ so we only need to find the values of $U$ in at least $deg(P)$ points. This can be done using:
  $$I(x)=\frac{R(x)}{Q(x)}=U(x)+\frac{V(x)}{Q(x)}P(x) \tag 1$$
  It's easy to see that if we evaluate $I$ in the roots of $P$ we can find the values of $U$, if we have multiple roots we also evaluate the derivatives of $I$.
- There are other methods using for example the roots of $Q$ in formula $(1)$ in which case we use limits and evaluating in some remarkable points such as $a,1,-1$ the roots of $P,R,Q$.

**Third** why we need this decomposition, there are a lot of applications of the decomposition like this in computing integrals and solving differential equations.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the denominator has only *simple* irreducible factors, it's rather straightforward. Here, for instance, I'll suppose $f,g$ have the same sign, so that $fx^2+g$  is irreducible and it has complex roots. The general strategy is to:

1. Multiply both sides of equality by $(dx+e)(fx^2+g)$. You obtain a polynomial identity:
   $$ax^2+bx+c=A(fx^2+g)+(Bx+C)(dx+e).$$
2. Set $x=-\dfrac ed\,$ and get an equation for $A$.
3. Set $x=\mathrm i\mkern 1.5mu\sqrt{-\dfrac gf}$. You get an equation with complex coefficients for $d$ and $e$, i.e. two equations with real coefficients.

Also remember you first have to divide (with remainder) the numerator by the denominator, so as to have a *proper*  rational function ($\deg$(numerator) $<\deg$(denominator)).

For a proper rational function, the decomposition theorem says they are are sums of *proper* rational functions with primary denominators (=powers of a single  irreducible polynomial) and $\deg$(numerator) $<\deg($irreducible polynomial). In the case of an irreducible quadratic polynomial, this means the numerator will have degree at most $1$.

Comment: I understand how to solve for the coefficients, but I do not understand how to choose what the polynomials on the RHS numerators will look like. For example, why is the numerator of the second fraction, $Bx+C$ and not just some number $h$.

Comment: Please see my  completed answer.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I appreciate your responses. Haven't yet digested what you've written, but I hope it will clarify my doubts.